# How to add slide show animation to my sider code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on a project for my school, I have a image slideshow.

When I click on an arrow the next image appears.

But I want it to slide and show the next picture.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("MySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<img class="MySlides" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports/" width="380px;" height="380px;">
<img class="MySlides" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/food/" width="380px;" height="380px;" style="display:none;">
<img class="MySlides" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/cats/" width="380px;" height="380px;" style="display:none;">
<span><a OnClick="plusDivs(1)" class="links">&#8249;</a></span>
<span><a OnClick="plusDivs(-1)"class="rechts">&#8250;</a></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, with real slide effect: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XMxGMw

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slide');
  console.log(slides.length);
  if (n < 0) {
    slideIndex = slides.length - 1;
    n = slides.length - 1;
  } else if (n > slides.length - 1) {
    slideIndex = 0;
    n = 0;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    var slide = slides[i];
    if (i < n) {
      slide.className = 'slide slide-previous';
    } else if (i === n) {
      slide.className = 'slide slide-selected';
    } else {
      slide.className = 'slide slide-next';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#slides-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 380px;
  height: 380px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 380px;
  width: 380px;
}

.slide-selected,
.slide-previous,
.slide-next {
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.slide-selected {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.slide-previous {
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.slide-next {
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="slides-container">
  <img class="slide" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports/">
  <img class="slide" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/food/">
  <img class="slide" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/cats/">
  <img class="slide" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/food/">
  <img class="slide" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/food/">
</div>
<span><a OnClick="plusDivs(-1)" class="links">&#8249;</a></span>
<span><a OnClick="plusDivs(1)"class="rechts">&#8250;</a></span>
```

Here is a more advanced version with automation and different animation: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ryqRKX

Comment: This one is really nice , Is there a possibility when you click on the arrow from the 3rd picture that it goes back to the first one ?

Comment: Yes sure, look the code pen at the end of the post. I update the first one.

Comment: Thanks , Can it just go from 1 2 3 and then back 1 2 3. Now it has a weird animation in it?

Comment: @Tinneveld.N it's more complicated, i haven't much time to do it. If you want to, you have to override the transition property on every slides, set the transform of all slide (except the previous selected one) to -100% or +100% (depending of wich transition you are doing 0 to last or last to 0). Then reset the transition property, and run the for.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

var index = 1;
var maxindex = $('#slideshow > div').length;

setInterval(function () {
    $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
    $('ul li').removeClass('active');
    $('ul li:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('active');
    index = index < maxindex - 1 ? index + 1 : 0;
}, 3000);

for (var i = 0; i < maxindex; i++) {
    $('ul').append('<li class="' + (i == 0 ? 'active' : '') + '"></li>');
}
```

```css
#slideshow {
    margin: 50px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#slideshow > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
}

#slideshow img {
    max-width:240px;
    max-height:240px;
}

ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
ul li {
    float:left;
    border-radius:10px;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border:1px solid white;
    background:grey;
}
ul li.active {
    background:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="slideshow">
<div>
<img class="MySlides" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/food/" width="380px;" height="380px;">
</div>
<div>
<img class="MySlides" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" width="380px;" height="380px; ">
 </div>
 <ul></ul>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Whay not using lovely jquery and css combination.  :)

Comment: He want the solution in his given code only :| Not any plugin ;)